# .NET async webservice call with a callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous, async-await

We have a legacy VB6 application that uses an ASMX webservice written in C# (.NET 4.5), which in turn uses a library (C#/.NET 4.5) to execute some business logic. One of the library methods triggers a long-running database stored procedure at the end of which we need to kick off another process that consumes the data generated by the stored procedure. Because one of the requirements is that control must immediately return to the VB6 client after calling the webservice, the library method is `async`, takes an `Action` callback as a parameter, the webservice defines the callback as an anonymous method and doesn't `await` the results of the library method call.

At a high level it looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Sample
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "urn:Services")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class MyWebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string Request(string request)
        {
            // Step 1: Call the library method to generate data
            var lib = new MyLibrary();
            lib.GenerateDataAsync(() =>
            {
                // Step 2: Kick off a process that consumes the data created in Step 1
            });

            return "some kind of response";
        }
    }

    public class MyLibrary
    {
        public async Task GenerateDataAsync(Action onDoneCallback)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", new SqlConnection("my DB connection string")))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    cmd.Connection.Open();

                    // Asynchronously call the stored procedure.
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // Invoke the callback if it's provided.
                    if (onDoneCallback != null)
                        onDoneCallback.Invoke();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle errors...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above works in local tests, but when the code is deployed as a webservice **Step 2** is never executed even though the **Step 1** stored procedure completes and generates the data.

Any idea what we are doing wrong?

Comment: Your local machine's firewall may be blocking the incoming connection...

Comment: As aside, I guess that Step 1 is calling `lib.GenerateDataAsync` (says `GenerateData` which is not shown). I think the issue is that the asmx request has finished executing and "is out the door", and there is "nowhere to execute" the callback. Have you tried awaiting that call?

Comment: Review your implementation of Request. If you are using async you have to use it in your whole pipeline for the most consistent solution.

Comment: @MarkLarter, thanks for noticing my typo, I've fixed it.

Awaiting the call in the web service would defeat the whole "fire and forget" approach to running the stored procedure. 

I agree that the likely cause is that the thread on which the call to `GenerateDataAsync` runs gets recycled by IIS by the time the call is finished, so there's no context for the callback to execute on. I am just hoping someone who has "been there, done that" can suggest a workaround.

Comment: @Eser, there is no incoming connection that could be blocked by the firewall. The concept of a callback doesn't involve the web server miraculously calling back to the client machine.

Comment: @CaspianCanuck Definitely BTDT, but not since .NET 2.0 (BeginAsync...). Awaiting should still free the IIS worker thread to handle other web requests, so you'd not be blocking your request pipeline. Not sure what else you need to accomplish with "fire and forget", so admittedly this may not be enough for your needs.

Comment: @CaspianCanuck Then how do you think it is happening? Either client will create a connection to server open while session is active (for ex WebSockets), or server will try to connect to client (like done in old *Remoting* framework).

Comment: @Eser, the code that runs inside the callback has nothing to do with the client, it just calls another webservice. So no communication needs to flow between this webservice and the client in any direction.

Comment: @CaspianCanuck OK You know better, but then why are you here? (I think I am not able to express myself.) To make it short, I did the same thing last week by using SignalR.....

Comment: @MarkLarter, thanks for putting me on the right track with your comment about BeginAsync!  I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

it is dangerous to leave tasks running on IIS, the app domain may be shut down before the method completes, that is likely what is happening to you. If you use [`HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636892(v=vs.110).aspx) you can tell IIS that there is work happening that needs to be kept running. This will keep the app domain alive for a extra 90 seconds (by default)

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Sample
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "urn:Services")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class MyWebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string Request(string request)
        {
            // Step 1: Call the library method to generate data
            var lib = new MyLibrary();
            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((token) =>
                lib.GenerateDataAsync(() =>
                {
                    // Step 2: Kick off a process that consumes the data created in Step 1
                }));

            return "some kind of response";
        }
    }

    public class MyLibrary
    {
        public async Task GenerateDataAsync(Action onDoneCallback)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", new SqlConnection("my DB connection string")))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    cmd.Connection.Open();

                    // Asynchronously call the stored procedure.
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // Invoke the callback if it's provided.
                    if (onDoneCallback != null)
                        onDoneCallback();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle errors...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want something more reliable than 90 extra seconds see the article "[Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)" by Stephen Cleary for some other options.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my problem that involves the old-style (Begin/End) approach to asynchronous execution of code:

```
    public void GenerateData(Action onDoneCallback)
    {
        try
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", new SqlConnection("my DB connection string"));
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(
                (IAsyncResult result) =>
                {
                    cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
                    cmd.Dispose();

                    // Invoke the callback if it's provided, ignoring any errors it may throw.
                    var callback = result.AsyncState as Action;
                    if (callback != null)
                        callback.Invoke();
                },
                onUpdateCompleted);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle errors...
        }
    }
```

The `onUpdateCompleted` callback action is passed to the `BeginExecuteNonQuery` method as the second argument and is then consumed in the `AsyncCallback` (the first argument). This works like a charm both when debugging inside VS and when deployed to IIS.